# ng-tags-input and bootstrap for dumb

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-tags-input

need some help
trying to add ng-tag for register page on site,but i really dunno how to do it

i'm using bootstrap and jinja 2, basicly my form looks like:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputInterest" class="col-lg-3 control-label">your interest</label>

<div class="col-lg-9">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputInterest" name="interest" placeholder="interest">
            </div>
        </div>
```

what i need:
change the usual str to tags with ng-tag

thx guys so much, w8 for answer:3

Answer (score 0):

To install a ng tag in your div classes here:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputInterest" class="col-lg-3 control-label">your interest</label>

<div class="col-lg-9">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputInterest" name="interest" placeholder="interest">
            </div>
        </div>
```

You first need to have a Js File(In this case i name it app.js):

That has the following in it(You can change myApp to any string...):

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

and then you need a controller(In this case i name it mainController.Js):

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 

}]);
```

Now you can implement the n-g tag to your div like this:

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-controller="MainController">
         <label for="inputInterest" class="col-lg-3 control-label">your interest</label>

    <div class="col-lg-9" ng-controller="MainController">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputInterest" name="interest" placeholder="interest">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Learn more [here](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-angularjs) about angular js!

Comment: thx for your answer. i do same as u say, but nothing is working :\ no allusion for tags there :( can u just tell me ths step by step, pls :3 with respect, cawabanga

Comment: You implement an ng-tag, by making a ng-app, and ng-controller in your body